# Change the Slug of Post Type post to baseurl/post/%postname%

Tags: posts, permalinks, slug

I have been searching around but i cant anywhere find the answer to my question: How to change the post slug for all posts (and the categories etc.). Without affecting other pages/ custom post urls.
So i want to change the url for default posts from:

url/postname > url/news/postname

Without affecting page urls and or custom post type urls. The only method i have so far found that achieved what i was looking for was:

http://wordimpress.com/how-to-add-a-custom-permalink-structure-for-only-the-wordpress-default-post-type/

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_new_default_post_type', 1 );
function my_new_default_post_type() {

register_post_type( 'post', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
    ),
    'public'  => true,
    '_builtin' => false, 
    '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', 
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'post' ),
    'query_var' => false,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
) );
}
```

By re-registering the post type. But this also has the side effect that it creates a second menu item on the left side of the admin panel called post. They both contain the same data though.

Hopefully somebody has an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to reregister the default `post` post type. You can just add a prefix to the permalink structure using the Permalinks settings, found under the main Settings menu in your WordPress administration panel:

[image: Example of the permalinks settings]

Comment: And this wont change all the urls for the pages?  (cant try it at this current moment so)

Comment: Correct. The default WordPress pages will just use `domain.tld/page-slug` as they always do.

Comment: Yes that indeed did the trick. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Make sure to set "with_front" to "false" on Custom Post Type initializations to avoid having the "blog" prefix on your Custom Post Types.

Comment: Thx, Aternus. Also, after setting with_front to false, go to /wp-admin/options-permalink.php in the backend (just visit the page once) - this will call `flush_rewrite_rules()` after which the new links will work correctly